# tkinter window destruction and defining buttons

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-button

The windows created after pressing the left or right button can't destroy themselves, and instead destroy the first window. I think this is because they are something like sub-windows of the first one, So I am unsure how to get them to destroy themselves instead. The other problem I have is that I want to automatically place buttons onto a new window by defining it, but I don't know how to do that.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#Create an instance of tkinter window
fst = Tk()
fst.title("First")

#Define a function to close the window
def close_fst():
    fst.destroy()


#Define a function
def open_snd():
    fst = Tk()
    fst.title("Second")
    fst.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    Label(fst, text="Second",font=('Georgia 15 bold')).pack(pady=30)
    btn = Button(fst, text="X",command=close_fst)
    btn.pack(side=TOP, anchor='e', padx=5, pady=5)
    btn1 = Button(fst, text="<-",command=open_snd)
    btn1.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor='w', padx=5, pady=5)
    btn2 = Button(fst, text="->",command=open_trd)
    btn2.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor='e', padx=5, pady=5)    



def open_trd():
    fst = Tk()
    fst.title("Third")
    fst.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    Label(fst, text="Third",font=('Georgia 15 bold')).pack(pady=30)
    btn = Button(fst, text="X",command=close_fst)
    btn.pack(side=TOP, anchor='e', padx=5, pady=5)
    btn1 = Button(fst, text="<-",command=open_snd)
    btn1.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor='w', padx=5, pady=5)
    btn2 = Button(fst, text="->",command=open_trd)
    btn2.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor='e', padx=5, pady=5)    


btn = Button(fst, text="X",command=close_fst)
btn.pack(side=TOP, anchor='e', padx=5, pady=5)
btn1 = Button(fst, text="<-",command=open_snd)
btn1.pack(side=LEFT, anchor='s', padx=5, pady=5)
btn2 = Button(fst, text="->",command=open_trd)
btn2.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor='s', padx=5, pady=5)    


Label(fst, text="First",font=('Georgia 15 bold')).pack(pady=30)
fst.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```

Comment: Isn't this obvious that  `close_fst` function will close first window?

Comment: Having multiple instances of Tk in the same application is not recommended. If you want multiple windows use Toplevel for the children of the parent window.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you did in `close_fst()` function is destroying the global variable which is the first window titled "First", this is because the `close_fst()` doesn't have access to the other variables inside `open_snd()` and `open_trd()`, if you want to access them declare them global and change their names to be different from the first one, then you will be able to destroy them inside your function one by one.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#Create an instance of tkinter window
fst = Tk()
fst.title("First")

#Define a function to close the window
def close_fst():
    fst.destroy()
    fst1.destroy()
    fst2.destroy()


#Define a function
def open_snd():
    global fst1
    fst1 = Tk()
    fst.title("Second")
    fst.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    Label(fst, text="Second",font=('Georgia 15 bold')).pack(pady=30)
    btn = Button(fst, text="X",command=close_fst)
    btn.pack(side=TOP, anchor='e', padx=5, pady=5)
    btn1 = Button(fst, text="<-",command=open_snd)
    btn1.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor='w', padx=5, pady=5)
    btn2 = Button(fst, text="->",command=open_trd)
    btn2.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor='e', padx=5, pady=5)    



def open_trd():
    global fst2
    fst2 = Tk()
    fst.title("Third")
    fst.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    Label(fst, text="Third",font=('Georgia 15 bold')).pack(pady=30)
    btn = Button(fst, text="X",command=close_fst)
    btn.pack(side=TOP, anchor='e', padx=5, pady=5)
    btn1 = Button(fst, text="<-",command=open_snd)
    btn1.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor='w', padx=5, pady=5)
    btn2 = Button(fst, text="->",command=open_trd)
    btn2.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor='e', padx=5, pady=5)    


btn = Button(fst, text="X",command=close_fst)
btn.pack(side=TOP, anchor='e', padx=5, pady=5)
btn1 = Button(fst, text="<-",command=open_snd)
btn1.pack(side=LEFT, anchor='s', padx=5, pady=5)
btn2 = Button(fst, text="->",command=open_trd)
btn2.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor='s', padx=5, pady=5)    


Label(fst, text="First",font=('Georgia 15 bold')).pack(pady=30)
fst.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```

I hope that helps !